# Scrolling to Second Stage Recycle Bin

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, recycle-bin

Is there a quicker way of getting to the Second Stage Recycle Bin without having to scroll down through the first Recycle Bin?

We sometimes have hundreds or thousands of files in the first stage bin and it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the position of "second stage recycle bin" link on first recycle bin page.

However, you can directly access the second level of recycle bin using URL in below format:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=13
```

You may share this URL with all users via email or add it as a link in site navigation or quick links web part on any site page.

---

**Update**:

If above URL is not working for you, try this URL:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5#view=13
```

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, the above link takes me straight to the first stage recycle bin.  Copying and pasting the url from the second stage also takes me to the first stage.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this link works https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5#view=13  Many thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The Recycle Bin in general could use an overhaul. I would suggest submitting a suggestion at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472, but make sure to search for a similar suggestions first.

Comment: Thank you Trevor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut key Fn+End /Ctrl+End to the bottom of the page in the first Recycle Bin.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, _layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5#view=13
This is the url on the link displayed in the footer.
Note that once you are viewing the second-stage recycle bin, the url will update to _layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=13, so if you refresh the page you will be redirected to the first-stage recycle bin url, _layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5